# Argument of type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, and I'm getting the following error which I don't understand:

> Argument of type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You don't need to include the source of your entire application, just enough to demonstrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have a variable which can be a number or null or undefined and you are trying to put it in another variable that can only be a number. This is incompatible

Answer (score 0):

This error message can happen when you're attempting to assign a value of a "wider" type to a "narrower" type. This means that there is a larger potential range of values for the "source" type than there are for the "target" type.

In your case, the type `number | null | undefined` is wider than `number`, since `null` and `undefined` are values allowed by the former but not the latter.

For example, the following will produce the same error you're seeing:

```
let numberOnly: number = 0
function assign(value: number | null | undefined) {
    numberOnly = value;
}
```

This will cause a TypeScript error, since `null` and `undefined` are not of type `number`.

There are lots of ways around this, but it's somewhat dependent on how you want your application to work. For example, if you have `null` or `undefined`, do you want to just not do anything further? If we did this for the example above, it might look like this:

```
let numberOnly: number = 0
function assign(value: number | null | undefined) {
    // if value is null or undefined, don't do anything
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
       numberOnly = value;
    }
}
```

Another option might be to assign a default value. Again, updating the first example:

```
let numberOnly: number = 0
function assign(value: number | null | undefined) {
    // if value is null or undefined, use a default of "123"
    numberOnly = value ?? 123;
}
```

It's really up to you, and what makes sense for your application. For more info, I'd suggest reading the [TypeScript docs on Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).